# SQL Error ORA-00984: column(145) not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

*I understand that this question has been asked before, but none of the other answers have solved my problem

PROBLEM: trying to insert into SQL table

here is my table --

[image]

here is my statement --

```
INSERT INTO IFS_APP_HOLIDAY_UI VALUES("Calendar", "Russ", "russ.wilson@gmail.com", "2018", "50", "50", "25", "DP", "0", "0", "6/12/2018", "Wilson);
```

here is my error --

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
INSERT INTO IFS_APP_HOLIDAY_UI VALUES("Calendar", "Russ", "russ.wilson@gmail.com", "2018", "50", "50", "25", "DP", "0", "0", "6/12/2018", "Wilsom")
Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 139
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You may want to remove your personal information from the error.

Comment: Shouldn't your values be escaped with single quotes `'` ?

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. a column named `"Calendar"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Calendar'`-

Comment: "Calendar" is interpreted as an object identifier as its double quoted.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218